How to change a VMs disk hardware/model name?
I'm trying to change the hardware/model name of a Vm's disk. I am using VMware Workstation pro right now, so i tried adding this to the .vmx:
disk.enableUUID = "TRUE"
This did not do what i tried to do, in the Task Manager (and device manager) it still says "VMWare NVME Disk". Is there a way to change that?
Obviously, VMware is preferred, but i should be able to change to virtualbox.

What are you looking to change it to?

It's pretty much anything else than it is right now.

The name of a device is determined by the guest OS, not the host
